# Feed dialog link redirects to completely blank page

Tags: facebook, dialog, send

I've got a button on my site that links to this send dialog:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=167532856763050&link=http://localhost:3000/register?invitecode=99bb05&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/feed
```

The link leads to an entirely blank page: nothing in the head or body tags.  The app ID is valid and the link and redirect_uri exist.  In the app settings, I have my site URL set to `http://localhost:3000` and my App Domains set to `localhost`.

Any idea why I'm getting a blank page?

(Edited to fix typo in URL unrelated to problem)

Comment: Well, now it's giving me a "'link' is invalid" error.  Ideas?

Comment: I just tried subbing out 'localhost:3000' with the production URL and it's working.  Now the only problem is that the autocomplete function for the "to" field in the resulting dialog doesn't work, so the message won't send.  Facebook rage.

Comment: Sorry this question is such a mess.  I blame the Facebook documentation.

Comment: When I come to think of it maybe you can't use localhost, as the users you have shared it with will be taken to localhost on their systems and not on yours???

Comment: I'm using localhost to test this on my local dev instance.  When used in production, I'll use production URLs.